# add flex controls to a custom block like a "row" or "stack"

Tags: block-editor

I have a custom block that I want to act as a flex row or stack for organizing child blocks. I know how to add constrained layout controls by adding `"__experimentalLayout": true` to my block.json, but I can't figure out how to further add flex layout controls.

For reference this is the regular layout controls that you would see on a group block

[image]

And here are the controls I want instead, as seen when selecting row or stack.

[image]

I feel like it can't be that complicated but after hours of research and referencing the src files for the group block, I can't figure out how to apply this.

In the code view of the gutenberg editor I've been able get these controls to show by adding `{"layout":{"type":"flex"}}` to the block. For example:

```
<!-- wp:my-blocks/custom-block {"layout":{"type":"flex"}} -->
```

While that works, I want the block to function this way out of the box.

Other things I have tried, none of which have worked;

```
return (

    <div {...blockProps} layout={{type: 'flex', flexWrap: 'nowrap'}} >
        <InnerBlocks />
    </div>

)
```

---

```
    const blockProps = useBlockProps({
        layout: {
            type: 'flex', 
            flexWrap: 'nowrap'
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should use `InspectorControls` https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/block-controls-toolbar-and-sidebar/, add appropriate components (you can inspect them with react developer tools when enabling DEBUG_SCRIPTS to true in wp-config and find them in blocks which have them) and build functionality so these components change attribute values, css class names are applied accordingly based on these attributes and add appropriate css for these classes.